# Using dplyr to count by group but include when there is 0 for a combination in R

Tags: r, dplyr, count, tidyverse

Here is an example of my data:

```
data1 <- data.frame("Group1" = c("A","A","B","C"), "Group2" = c("Green", "Blue", "Green", "Purple"))
```

My "Group1" variable can be A, B, or C. and my "Group2" variable can be Green, Blue, or Purple.

When I try running this code:

```
count <- data1 %>% group_by(Group1, Group2) %>%  summarise(n = n())
```

I get this output:

[image]

However, I want it to count all of the possible combinations of Group1 and Group2 even when it isn't present in the table. It would look like this:

```
 desired_output <- data.frame("Group1" = c("A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
 "Group2" = c("Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Green", "Blue", 
 "Purple"), "n" = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

Thank you!

Comment: One option is to make sure you are using factors and then make sure not to drop groups: `data1 %>% mutate(across(Group1:Group2, factor)) %>% group_by(Group1, Group2, .drop=FALSE) %>%  summarise(n = n())`